# Parse a specific number of lines from a previously parsed value

Tags: parsing, pyparsing

I'm using pyparsing to ingest the [gEDA](http://www.gpleda.org) schematic/symbol file format.  Most is straight-forward, but I'm not sure how to match a number of following lines specified by an integer field on the initial line.

A text object has a format like:

```
(other objects)
T x y color size vis snv angle align num_lines
Text line one
Line two of the text
Finally, the 'num_lines'th line
(other objects)
```

with *num_lines* an integer.  This style is used for a few other types also.

As a work-around, I define such lines as anything **not** matching a valid object type.  Technically, such object-like lines are allowed in text objects

```python
text_meta = Type("T") + coord + color + size + visibility + show_name_value \   
            + angle + alignment + num_lines + EOL                                   
text_data_line = ~obj + LineStart() + SkipTo(LineEnd()) + EOL                   
text_data = Group(OneOrMore(text_data_line)).setResultsName('text')             
text_data = text_data.setParseAction(lambda t: '\n'.join(t[0]))                 
text = text_meta + text_data
```

Generating a match rule on the fly like:

```python
def genLineMatcher(n):
    return (LineStart() + Skipto(LineEnd()) + EOL)*n
```

is on the table, but I'm not sure how to specify the rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Generating a match rule on the fly...

You are actually on the right track.  The way a rule is created on the fly is to define the variable length expression as a Forward(), and then in a parse action inserting the actual rule when the count field gets parsed.

Fortunately, pyparsing already has this implemented, in the helper method `countedArray`.  If you change your expression to:

```
text_meta = (Type("T") + coord + color + size + visibility + show_name_value +
               angle + alignment + countedArray(EOL + restOfLine)("lines"))
```

I think this will do what you want. Then you can retrieve the array of lines using the "lines" results name.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, browser cache and a "go home" crossed with finding countedArray earlier.  Such ability will make pyparsing a go-to tool, thanks for writing and sharing it!

Answer (score 0):

The pyparsing helper function 'countedArray(expr)' is almost what's needed.  Parser definition and modified helper function:

```python
def numLinesList(expr, name=None):                                                                                                                                                                        
    """Helper to snarf an end-of-line integer and match 'expr' N times after.                                                                                                                        
    Almost exactly like pyparsing.countedArray.                                                                                                                                                      
    Matches patterns of the form::                                                                                                                                                                   
        ... num_lines                                                                                                                                                                                
        line one                                                                                                                                                                                     
        line two                                                                                                                                                                                     
        num_lines'th line                                                                                                                                                                            
    """                                                                                                                                                                                              
    arrayExpr = Forward()                                                                                                                                                                            
    def numLinesAction(s, l, t):                                                                                                                                                                     
        n = int(t[0])                                                                                                                                                                                
        arrayExpr << (n and Group(And([expr]*(n+1))) or Group(empty))                                                                                                                                
        return []                                                                                                                                                                                    
    matcher = Word(nums).setParseAction(numLinesAction, callDuringTry=True) \                                                                                                                        
              + arrayExpr                                                                                                                                                                            
    # remove first empty string                                                                                                                                                                      
    matcher.addParseAction(lambda t: [t[0][1:]])                                                                                                                                                     
    if name:
        matcher = matcher.setResultsName(name)                                                                                                                                                           
    return matcher

text_meta = Type("T") + coord + color + size + visibility + show_name_value \   
        + angle + alignment
text_data_line = SkipTo(LineEnd()) + EOL
text_data = numLinesList(text_data_line, 'text')
text = text_meta + text_data
```

For an input snippet of:

```
...
T 41600 47800 9 10 1 0 0 0 2                                                                                                                                                                         
This is line 1                                                                                                                                                                                       
line 2 is here...                                                                                                                                                                                    
T 41600 47000 9 10 1 0 0 0 2                                                                                                                                                                         
Another first line                                                                                                                                                                                   
second line foo
```

This outputs:

```
['T', 41600, 47800, '9', 10, True, '0', 0, 0, ['This is line 1', 'line 2 is here...']]
['T', 41600, 47000, '9', 10, True, '0', 0, 0, ['Another first line', 'second line foo']]
```